# Dynamic Add queue Consumers Spring Issue

Tags: spring-boot, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am trying to add new queues to an existing listener in exclusive mode but I am having issues.
Code :

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/consumer")
    public void consumer() {
        Set<String> queue = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Test queue1", "Test queue2", "Test queue3"));
//        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            addQueueToListener("Test container1", queue);
//        }
    }
public void addQueueToListener(String containerId, String queueName) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer listener = (SimpleMessageListenerContainer)
                rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(containerId);
        if (Objects.nonNull(listener)) {
            String[] queueNames = listener.getQueueNames();
            System.out.println("Queue Names: " + Arrays.toString(queueNames) + " going to Add: " + queueName);
            System.out.println("search result for queue name: " + queueName + "     -->" + Arrays.binarySearch(queueNames, queueName));
            //do not add same queue name to listener
            if (Arrays.binarySearch(queueNames, queueName) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Adding queue: " + queueName);
                listener.addQueueNames(queueName);
                System.out.println("added queue: " + queueName);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addQueueToListener(String containerId, Set<String> queueName) {
        for (String queue : queueName) {
            addQueueToListener(containerId, queue);
        }
    }
```

Rabbit Listener Code:

```java
@RabbitListener(id = "Test container1", queues = "#{rabbitMQConsumer.getEntriesQueueName()}", containerFactory = "consumerBatchContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessageBatch(List<Message> messages) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        for (Message message : messages) {
            Thread.sleep(30000);
//      ObjectMapper jsonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
//      Employee employee = jsonObjectMapper.readValue(Arrays.toString(message.getBody()), Employee.class);
            String queueName = (String) message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().get("queueName");
            System.out.println("RabbitMQConsumer.receiveMessage QueueName:" + queueName);
//      System.out.println("Recieved Message From RabbitMQ: " + employee + "      QueueName:"+ queueName);
        }
    }

    public List<String> getEntriesQueueName() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
//        return Arrays.asList("Test queue1", "Test queue2", "Test queue3");
    }
```

Error: when I am setting listener.setIsExclusive(true);

```
Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - queue 'Test queue3' in vhost 'my_vhost' in exclusive use, class-id=60, method-id=20)
```

even tried setting exclusive on Rabbitlistener

```java
@RabbitListener(id = "Test container1", queues = "#{rabbitMQConsumer.getEntriesQueueName()}", containerFactory = "consumerBatchContainerFactory", exclusive = true)
```

but same error.

Code Reference: https://github.com/rajat-g/SpringBootRabbitMQConsumer

Comment: You need to show how you are declaring the queue - it looks like there is another consumer already on that queue.

Comment: @GaryRussell Here is the full code along with versions I used. There are 2 urls /producer and /consumer. using /consumer I am facing issue. Thanks in advance.
https://github.com/rajat-g/SpringBootRabbitMQConsumer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [bug in the listener container when you call `addQueueNames`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1246), we end up recycling the consumers multiple times and there's a race - we don't wait for the consumer to be canceled.

Use `listener.addQueues(new Queue(queueName));` instead.

Also, I moved `setExclusive` to the container factory bean...

```
factory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> container.setExclusive(true));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Sir.
I want to know will it make a difference if I use exclusive at listener level that is like this -
```@RabbitListener(id = "Test container1", queues = "#{rabbitMQConsumer.getEntriesQueueName()}", containerFactory = "consumerBatchContainerFactory", exclusive = true)```
Also, its working with what you told but it is I think wrong as when I run it -
it is fetching data from queue 3 15 times then from queue 2 10 times and from queue 2 5 times and then working fine that is 5 in round robin fashion. Why there are 15 unacknowledged message when my batch size is 5

Comment: It makes no difference how you set the container's exclusive flag - via the factory, the container itself, or the annotation - they all set the same flag. I think the behavior you observe is beecause you are adding them one-at-a-time. It is more efficient if you add all three in one call (and you should then get a more balanced distribution).

Comment: The `preFetchCount` needs to be greater than or equal to the batch size. Otherwise you will never get a full batch.

Comment: ok I will check that. Also, I want to know which is better container factory in terms of performance or both are same? batch listener or a simple one with the same size/prefetch count 5.

Comment: also if I do not set preFetchCount in batch consumer/listener then it will be same as batch size right??

Comment: No; it defaults to 250. The direct container is better for adding queues at runtime because it doesn't recycle the consumers; but it doesn't support batching because the listener is called directly from the amqp-client thread. You really only need batching if you need to process records in a batch (e.g. to store in a DB in a single transaction).

Comment: using ```listener.addQueues(new Queue(queueName));``` this It worked on 1 PC but on my other PC I got same error of channel shutdown. but when I added Thread.sleep inside for loop of method
```public void addQueueToListener(String containerId, Set<String> queueName)``` it worked fine. Please check this too. Maybe there is race condition in that too. Tried this couple of times also with exact same code but same result.